# rar library in actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, rar

Wondering if anyone knows of any opensource rar library for actionscript, similar to fzip, which works for zip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see any on a quick Google search, so my guess is no. However, I did find a few open source Java implementations, such as the library used by [Catacombae](http://www.catacombae.org/jlrarx.html#rarlib). You could then try and use something like [j2as3](http://code.google.com/p/j2as3/wiki/PageName) to convert it to Actionscript. You would just need to re-implement anything that uses generics or Enums to a native AS alternative.

Comment: was thinking I'd have to try something similar but didn't know about j2as3, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'similar to fzip' you are asking for a library with the ability to *create* RAR files, you are out of luck. The RAR format is proprietary, so you need WinRar to create them.

It may well be possible to find something that will *read* them, however.